# localstorage value is changed on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am creating an welcomescreen for my html app. and im using a welcomescreen plugin from github. you can check it here https://github.com/valnub/welcomescreen.js

now i want to show welcome screen when localstorage value is 0. and when close button of welcomescreen is clicked i am changing the localstorage value to 1. but on page refresh the localstorage value is again set to 0.

how to do that this is my js file.

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global console, Welcomescreen, $*/

// Init method

$(document).ready(function () {
  localStorage.setItem("welscreen", "0"); 
  var welcomeTour = localStorage.getItem("welscreen");
 
  if (welcomeTour == 0) {

    $(document).ready(function () {     
       var options = {
            'bgcolor': '#0da6ec',
            'fontcolor': '#fff',
            'onOpened': function () {
             console.log("welcome screen opened");
          console.log(welcomeTour);
       },
      'onClosed': function () {
          localStorage.setItem("welscreen","1");
       var welcomeTour = localStorage.getItem("welscreen");
       console.log("welcome screen closed");
       console.log(welcomeTour);
        }
     },
     welcomescreen_slides,
     welcomescreen;

    welcomescreen_slides = [
      {
        id: 'slide0',
        picture: '<div class="tutorialicon">♥</div>',
        text: 'Welcome to this tutorial. In the <a class="tutorial-next-
        link" href="#">next steps</a> we will guide you through a manual that will teach you how to use this app.'
      },
      {
        id: 'slide1',
        picture: '<div class="tutorialicon">✲</div>',
        text: 'This is slide 2'
      },
      {
        id: 'slide2',
        picture: '<div class="tutorialicon">♫</div>',
        text: 'This is slide 3'
      },
      {
        id: 'slide3',
        picture: '<div class="tutorialicon">☆</div>',
        text: 'Thanks for reading! Enjoy this app or go to <a class="tutorial-previous-slide" href="#">previous slide</a>.<br><br><a class="tutorial-close-btn" href="#">End Tutorial</a>'
      }
   ];

  welcomescreen = new Welcomescreen(welcomescreen_slides, options);

  $(document).on('click', '.tutorial-close-btn', function () {
    welcomescreen.close();
  });

  $('.tutorial-open-btn').click(function () {
    welcomescreen.open();  
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.tutorial-next-link', function (e) {
    welcomescreen.next(); 
  });

    $(document).on('click', '.tutorial-previous-slide', function (e) {
       welcomescreen.previous(); 
     });      
   });
 };
});
```

Comment: Of course it's set to `0`, you do that each time here: `localStorage.setItem("welscreen", "0");`. You need to check if it already exists or not.

Comment: because the local storage variable is set on the document.ready. its sets to zero each time the document is ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
localStorage.setItem("welscreen", "0"); 
var welcomeTour = localStorage.getItem("welscreen");
```

to this:

```
var welcomeTour = localStorage.getItem("welscreen");
if(welcomeTour === undefined || welcomeTour === null) {
   localStorage.setItem("welscreen", "0");
   welcomeTour = "0";
}
```